# Low server's performance when processing OLAP cubes

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, olap

We have multi-cpu server which performance in OLAP processing suddenly dropped. 
Something happened on night 29th December 2015, and OLAP cubes processing times grew from ~30 minutes per cube to 1.5h per cube. Where should I look to diagnose problems?

Any hardware problems are excluded. Also no one edited or even touched cubes on these days. All of hotfixes and updates are installed.

I already looked into Performance Monitor, but network looks ok, SQL isn't throttling, CPU and RAM aren't bottlenecks.

Everything looks and even works fine except those problems with processing.

Our setup: Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is to check the partitions and rows in them; if you have a very large number of rows in a single partition can indeed cause performance problems. Also I would check to see if aggregations are correct and remove/add those necessary for the specified cube.